# Can anyone prove $R - 0$ is algebraic set in some higher dimension?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is algebraic set where $X$ is zero set of $f$, now we have to prove that $Y$ = {$f(x) \not= 0$} is algebraic. For dimension 1 and real field, consider the function $f(x) = x$. Now clearly $R - 0$ cannot be algebraic in $R$ itself (because its uncountable), so our next hope is in some higher dimension. So can anyone find the appropriate function. I beforehand know that this theorem is true.

Comment: It's hard to understand your question, but I think you're saying whether $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{f(x)=0\}$ can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as an algebraic set.  If this is your question, consider $1-yf(x)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael Burr said, any hypersurface complement in $\mathbb A^n$ can be embedded as an affine variety in $\mathbb A^{n+1}$, with equation $f(x)t - 1 = 0$, where $t$ is your new coordinate. The projection $\mathbb A^{n+1} \to \mathbb A^n$ restricted to this variety is an isomorphism onto the complement of your hypersurface. As an example, $GL_n$ can be embedded in $\mathbb A^{n^2+1}$ as an algebraic variety, with equation $\det(M)t = 1$.